# Toad connection issue with Oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

I have installed Toad 12.8. However, it says that `You do not have any oracle homes installed`.

Please advise me. My older toad 12 still works and is able to find oracle home.

I am also getting

```
Access violation at address 0000000008C3A9DA in module 'Toad.exe'. Read of address 0000000000000090.
```

on TNSNames Editor.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be that your TOAD now is 64bit and your oracle home is 32bit or vice versa. The solution is to install the equivalent version for one of those to match.